# How to get an ACPI device's power state?

Tags: acpi

I'm looking for a programmatic way of querying an ACPI device's current power state (d-state) in Windows. It's not a USB device or display device. I couldn't find much on how I could access the current d-state through cmd line or an API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `PMCS – Power Management Control and Status` register on PCH embedded PCIe devices within the power management capability structure the capabilities list pointed to by the cap. pointer in the configuration space header for the seg:bus:device/function within the PCIe ECAM MMIO space. The capability structure contains the power management capability ID register, which contains the capability ID and the next capability pointer (which is an offset from the start of the configuration space for the device to the next capability structure), a PM capabilities register which has bits indicating D1 and D2 support or when a PME is triggered, and then the PMCS, which contains the Data, BSE and PMCR fields you see on a typical PCIe device.

The Intel PCH embedded PCIe devices support only states D0 and D3 hot and this can be read from the lower 2 bits of the PMCS register (only 00 and 11 are supported not 01 (D1) or 10 (D2). You'd need to write a kernel mode driver to read this on windows, to actually be able to make or retrieve a virtual address mapping to the physical MMIO address.

The BIOS checks for these capabilities and builds ACPI tables which are passed to the OS. An acpi.sys bus filter FiDO is loaded for each PCI device on the system and any other ACPI enabled device that isn't ACPI enumerated, due to the .inf for PCIe device's driver. Acpi.sys interprets the AML code in the ACPI table to handle SCI interrupts resulting from PME# triggered by PME messages sent by the PCIe device on a root port or PME# assertions by integrated devices such as a root port (both the root port (PCIe to PCIe Bridge) device and the device connected to the port have PM capabilities in their configuration space)